# How to remove a role from a user in a specified server using discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to implement a command for my bot that gives a role to a user for a determined amount of time, but I don't know how to make the bot remove or add a role to a user.

I need it to involve the server ID cause I plan on using the bot in multiple servers.

This is clearly wrong, but I hope it can help you all understand what I'm trying to do:

```
client.guilds.get(config.serverID).message.guild.members.get(userID).removeRole(config.donatorRole)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it! The only thing wrong is that `message` isn't a property of a [Guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild). Also, make sure to catch any errors if the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) returned by [`GuildMember.removeRole()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=removeRole) is rejected.

Here's a cleaned up example:

```js
const guild = client.guilds.get(config.serverID);
const member = guild.members.get(userID);

member.removeRole(config.donatorRole)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's my first js code so I'm struggling a little... Your code was exactly what I wanted! I'll study a little bit more about Promises that I sincerely still don't understand well, again, thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises) MDN documentation about asynchronous programming in JavaScript. Plenty of other documentation and guides are also available if you're still having a hard time grasping the concept (it is a lot for a beginner, so no worries). Glad I could help!